# Using @Value with Gauge framework

Tags: java, gauge

How can I use `@Value` with static Application context?

I built application using gauge spring demo https://github.com/getgauge-examples/ioc-spring.

App is started using `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext`, look at `RegisterIOC.java` in demo.

I want to use `@Value` in this project, but @Value do not see `application.yml` properties and i have exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder
```

Is there a way to customize this project and use @Value in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find solution with `aplication.yml`, but i created folder `env/default/default.properties` Gauge found properties and I was able to use `@Value`